Named pipe is closing on its own after reading one message
I am trying to run a named pipe server on a windows service for an ASP.net web API to communicate with. I have got the ASP.net to be able to send a message but immediately after reading from the pipe it closes, not just the client server connection, the named pipe service simply disposes itself. When I try to call write after reading to send returned data I get error "Cannot access a closed pipe." same error occurs when trying to call WaitForConnection(). I am not sure what is causing this and why it occurs. The Windows Service stays running so that isn't an issue.
Method to start named pipe server
private void StartNamedPipeServer()
{
// set up security
        PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

// create and handle named pipe
        pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("test", PipeDirection.In, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None, 1024, 1024, pipeSecurity);
        HandleNamedPipeConnections();
}

Method to handle the execution of named pipe
private void HandleNamedPipeConnections()
{
        while (true)
        {
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
                {
                    string request = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                    // Handle request here
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pipeServer.IsConnected)
                {
                    pipeServer.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
}

Method for setting up client
pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test", PipeDirection.InOut);
pipeClient.Connect();

using (StreamWriter writer = new(pipeClient))
{
    writer.WriteLine(request);
}


I think the new StreamReader(pipeServer) is to blame, when StreamReader closes, at the end of the using, it also closes the underlying stream (in your case, pipeServer)
There should be a leaveOpen parameter when creating the StreamReader, which stops it from closing the stream when the reader closes.
try:
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer, leaveOpen=true))


I had a suspicion this might be the case shortly after posting but got side tracked with other work. I am going to try this out right now and see if that works but this behavior seems odd. Why would StreamReader Dispose the passed in Stream. Why the heck is this the default behavior.
